# Excel FILTER function removes zeros - intended behaviour?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Whilst playing around with the FILTER function I noticed that when the same array is passed to both arguments (for "array" and "include") the function filters out any zero values.

Is this because zero is considered Falsey in Excel? I've tried googling but can't find a clear answer and `=0=FALSE` returns False, and I can't see reference to this zero-filtering functionality anywhere in the [FILTER function documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759).

The following result is what I see from `=FILTER(A2:A7, A2:A7)`:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Column A | Column A Filtered |
| **2** | -22 | -22 |
| **3** | 10 | 10 |
| **4** | 25 | 25 |
| **5** | -5 | -5 |
| **6** | 0 | 17 |
| **7** | 17 |  |

Finally is there anyway to suppress this? I'm trying to use FILTER to remove N/A values from an array with something like `=FILTER(A2:A8,IFERROR(A2:A8,FALSE))` but I want to keep zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel Formula `FALSE` = `0`.

You can see that with the following formula:

```
=--FALSE
```

If you look at the documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

The multi conditional example uses: `(C5:C20=H1)*(A5:A20=H2)` the `*` will cause the TRUE/FALSE to become `1/0` respectively and thus it will return an array of `1`s and `0`s.

So yes, when doing: `=FILTER(A2:A7, A2:A7)` any `0` in the list will be assumed as `FALSE`

Now to your wanted formula, instead of `IFERROR` use `NOT(ISERROR())`

```
=FILTER(A2:A8,NOT(ISERROR(A2:A8)))
```